# Computing Variance from co-variance matrix in OpenCV Expectation Max

Tags: matlab, opencv, covariance, gaussian

In opencv, the result of Expectation Max is given as a co-variance matrix. In my work, I have 2 distributions where I need to compute the similarities. I want to use the variance but its given only co-variance of the number of clusters:

I have 2 question that I need help on:

1. If my cluster is 1, than I assume that the co-variance = variance. Is it correct.?
2. How to compute variance from co-variance for cluster > 1 (if 1 is correct)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every cluster in your case is gaussian probability distribution density function. In onedimentional case its parameters are mean and variance.

In multidimentional case variance becomes covariance matrix.It describes ellipsoid axis directions and size.

You can reduce covariance to variance but you'll get circle or sphere instead ellipse or ellipsoid.

So ellipse axis directions will be eigenvectors of covariance matrix, and their halflengths will be square root of eigenvalues. Once you know ellipse axis you should deside the way you will convert it to circle. The radius you accept will be square root of variance.

But if you'll need compute probability you'll should compute covariance matrix from your variance by scaling identity matrix by factor equal to variance.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation. Can i just you few more question? Firstly, ellipse axis will be eigenvectors in 2D, therefore you mean I should convert to x^2 + y^2 = some variance. How I select this variance. ? How I know which one is the best?

Comment: Also I have 2 large dataset of 1000points in 4D vector. I want to compare the 2 using GMM and compute the distance between the 2 distribution so I can cluster similar points together. Do u think what I am doing is correct? Sorry I am just slowly entering this field so I am quiet lost at time. Thank you for your time. Happy New Year

Comment: Classical method of distance measurement for distributions is Kullback–Leibler divergence.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence

Comment: So basically I do this; I compute the PDF of 2 dataset and compute the distance using Kullback Leibler method and than project the points from the dataset using this threshold (the calculated distance). Is this correct?

Comment: Sorry, it seems I misunderstand you. Are you have one GMM model with 2 components? or you have 2 gmm models. In first case you can classify just by computing pdfs for all components at input point and assign class of component with greater pdf value.

Comment: You can find how to compute PDF for your case here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution . The parameters of PDF  (mean, covariance and mixture coefficient) you got from EM algorithm you use to estimate GMM. Take a look at: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/ml/doc/expectation_maximization.html#  it seems there all you need.

Comment: just one question. I am currently doing 1 GMM for each and clustering into 1 clusters only. Therefore I get variance of each from the co-variance however to compute bhattacharyya distance i need mean but my data vector is 4D hence i get 4 means. How can i know which one to select? Please help me

Comment: Well, I think you should think in matrix-vector way, not in scalar, then all things will easier. I think you does not need GMM (GMM is weighted mixture of gaussians, if you use two mixtures with one gaussian in each it degenerates to two simple multivariate gaussians PDF). You can find means and covars without using EM algorithm, ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution look at nondegenerate case). You can find bhattacharyya distance as describerd here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhattacharyya_distance see multivariate case. You have not 4 means, you have one 4-D mean.